# The sum of the series $1 + 2x + 3x^2 ...$

Tags: contest-math

My approach : I tried using integral calculus and using infinite geometric series..however it didn't match..any trick?

Comment: hint:  differentiate  $f(x)=\frac 1{1-x}=\sum x^n$, at least for $|x|<1$.

Comment: why are such clear duplicates not shut down immideatly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$$ Differentiating with respect to $x$ and assuming $|x|<1$, which guarantees uniform convergence:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=1+2x+3x^2+\dots.$$ (you should also check the radius of convergence of the resulting expression.)

---

An Alternative approach is based on the assumption of absolute convergence of the series:

$$S = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots$$
$$      + x + x^2 + \dots$$
$$          + x^2 + \dots$$
$$ \dots $$

Answer (score 1):

F = 1 + x + x^2 + ...

Your sum is 
F + x*F + x^2*F + x^3 * F ...

Comment: Even I got this answer ...I expect a more appropriate answer...Anyways, thanks for ur time